# How to invert the color in the terminal?

Tags: raspbian

I used setterm -inversescreen on to invert the color of the background and the text color but nothing happened. How do I invert the color?

Comment: What client are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [Putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) and [Solarized putty colours](https://github.com/altercation/solarized/tree/master/putty-colors-solarized)

[image]

To use it you load the registry files into your windows, open up putty, load the colour profile. Then adjust your connection settings and other tweaks. Save that to a new profile.

[image]